# Flatten List<A> where each A contains a List<B> for every distinct B

Tags: java, list, collections, java-stream

My goal is to expand `List<A>`, where each `A` has an attribute `List<B>` to a `List<A>`, where each `A` will contain a list with a single distinct object `B`.

Considering `A` and `B` have this structure:

```
class A{
  String idA;
  List<B> listOfB;
}

class B{
  Long idB;
  String name;
}
```

I'd like to expand the `List<A>` so that it contains an object `A` for each distinct contained object `B` (where two objects `B` are differentiated by the attribute `name`).
For example

```
[
  {
    "idA": 1,
    "listOfB": [
      {
        "idB": 3,
        "name": "Foo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "idA": 2,
    "listOfB": [
      {
        "idB": 3,
        "name": "Foo"
      },
      {
        "idB": 4,
        "name": "Bar"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

should be transformed to

```
  {
    "idA": 1,
    "listOfB": [
      {
        "idB": 3,
        "name": "Foo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "idA": 2,
    "listOfB": [
      {
        "idB": 3,
        "name": "Foo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "idA": 2,
    "listOfB": [
      {
        "idB": 4,
        "name": "Bar"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I do this using **streams**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement equals in B, this could be one of the solution.

```
        Set<B> bs = as.stream()
                .map(A::getListOfB)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        return bs.stream()
                .map(s -> as.stream()
                        .filter(a -> a.getListOfB().contains(s))
                        .map(a -> new A(a.idA, List.of(s)))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                )
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please note I have created all param constructor in both A & B.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your explanation and example you've provided, you need to build a resulting list comprised of objects `A`, where each element will hold a reference to a list with one element of type `B`.

A singleton-list and a new object `A` that will hold this list have to be created for every distinct object `B` initially contained in a particular object `A`.

For that, you can use a `flatMap()` operation, which takes an element and returns a stream of flattened elements. Operation `distinct()` applied in the nested stream will ensure that only unique objects `B` will be peeked from each list (I assume that `hashCode/equals` contract was correctly implemented in the class `B`).

```
List<A> listB = getSourceList();

listB.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.getListOfB().stream()
                  .distinct()
                  .map(b -> new A(a.getIdA(), List.of(b))))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```